# make table rows from foreach loop?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been stuck on this for some time now; I'm using `ASP.NET` `MVC 4` and `C#` for a web application.  I read in an Excel file from my controller, and I have a `List` of all the cells which I send back to my `view`.  This is what I'm using:

```
<table>
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.range)
{ 
    <tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
    {
        <td>
            <input style="width:50px;" value=@item />
        </td>
    }
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Basically, I have 6 columns in `Excel`.  I am trying to recreate the `Excel` in my `view`.
But there is something wrong with my `for loop`, it's doing each cell 6 times.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does that because you tell it to in the `for` loop. Perhaps you should remove it.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  @foreach (var item in ViewBag.range)
  { 

    <td>
        <input style="width:50px;" value=@item />
    </td>

  }
 </tr>
</table>
```

---

**EDIT**

This will place the items inside of `range` into rows which have 6 columns each.

```
@{
 int total = 0; 
}

<table>
  @foreach (var item in ViewBag.range)
  { 
    if( total % 6 == 0 ){
        @:<tr>
    }
    <td>
        <input style="width:50px;" value=@item />
    </td>
    if( total+1 % 7 == 0 ){
        @:</tr>
    }
    total++;
  }
</table>
```

Comment: Im trying to get 6 <td> 's  in a table row, then i want it to go on next row. how can I do this?

Comment: @archie - I guess it depends on the data structure. The code above assumes there are 6 items in `ViewBag.range`. Based on that assumption, it will make 6 `td` elements. What is in range?

Comment: range is cells A1 to F29 in my excel sheet, so 6 columns

Comment: so in essence, theres 174 items in the loop, and i want to put them into rows of 6 elements in each row

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont have enough information about range....I did the following with assumption ; modify and use it

```
 @{var counter=0}
    <table>
          <tr>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.range)
    { 
         counter++;
        <td>
            <input style="width:50px;" value=@item />
        </td>
         if(counter%6==0)
         {
           @:</tr>
            if(counter<ViewBag.range.Count)
            {
             @:<tr>
               }
         }

    }
    </table>
```

Comment: no thats not what I am trying to do, I want the Viewbag to loop through and get the first 6 values in a row, then loop through and get the another 6 values in the second row and so on..

Comment: In that case use a variable counter and increment it every time you add a column, if the count%6==0 , that is the time to close the old row and create a new one

Comment: thanks, could you please provide me a sample of how to do it?

Comment: Can you tell me strictly what is in range?